# Creating a Named Cron Job

Tags: cron

How do you create a cron job from the command line, so that it shows up with a name in gnome-schedule?

I know how to create a cron job using crontab. However, all my jobs show up with a blank name. I'd like to better document my jobs so I can easily identify them in gnome-schedule, or similar cron wrapper.

Comment: In addition to answering, I gotta say thanks for pointing me to gnome-schedule! Never heard of it before, but it's useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, just made a cronjob in Scheduler, and took a look at my crontab file, and it looked like this:

```
0 0 * * * ls >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_1
```

Notice the `JOB_ID_1` at the end.

I went into `~/.gnome/gnome-scheduler/`, looked at the files there, and there was one named just `1` (as in the number "one") which had a bit of info, including the name

```
ver=3
title=Hello
desc=
nooutput=1
```

So, I made a second cronjob:

```
0 0 * * * ls -al >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_2
```

Copied the file `1` to `2` to match the `JOB_ID_2`, changed the description, making the file as:

```
ver=3
title=This is a test
desc=
nooutput=1
```

Then I switched over to Gnome-Schedule, and it had added the cronjob, and had the name updated.

Follow the same steps, and you should be able to manually name any cronjob you want

Comment: Thank you. Great find. Also note there's a "last_id" file, which appears to track the last last job id created, so that will need to be updated as well.